# How can I Insert a list of arrays in SQL with WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert some arrays(users) into my SQL table where user_login does not already exist.

```
INSERT INTO wp_post_count(user_login, post_count, comment_count, premium) 
SELECT
      FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3, FieldName4
FROM
  (
    Values
        ( "a",0,0,0),
        ( "a",0,0,0 ),
        ( "a",0,0,0 ),
        ( "a",0,0,0)
  ) AS TempTableName ( FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3, FieldName4 )
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT 1
      FROM wp_post_count
      WHERE user_login = a
  )
```

When I run this statement I get the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Values
        ( "a",0,0,0),
        ( "a",0,0,0 ),
        ( "a",0,0,0 ),
' at line 6
```

I am not sure what the syntax error is that could be causing this. Is there something I am missing or a better way to do this?

Comment: Oh you use mySQL, try using with union all instead of (VALUES (...)). Or directly the values themselves without (VALUES ( ...)).

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: what does `select version()` show?

Comment: @ysth  version 5.7.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Table for  the FROM clause

So a `UNION ALL` would give you that

```
INSERT INTO wp_post_count(user_login, post_count, comment_count, premium) 
SELECT
      FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3, FieldName4
FROM
  (  SELECT  "a" AS FieldName1 ,0 AS FieldName2 ,0 AS  FieldName3,0 AS FieldName4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  "a",0,0,0
    UNION ALL
          SELECT  "a",0,0,0
    UNION ALL
            SELECT  "a",0,0,0
    
  ) AS TempTableName 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT 1
      FROM wp_post_count
      WHERE user_login = a
  )
```